# bazel cc_test test_env options

Tags: c++, bazel, test-environments

When I use a cc_test like:

```
cc_test(
    name = "xxx_test",
    srcs = glob([
        'xxx.cpp',
    ]),
    linkopts = [
        "-L/usr/local/lib",
        "-lcppunit",
        "-ldl",
        "-lz",
        "-ltbb",
        "-llz4",
        "-lzstd"
    ],
    deps = [
        ":feature_generator"
    ],
)
```

I need to run this cmd:

```
./bazel test @xxx//xxx:xxx_test --test_output=errors --test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

How can I omit it `"--test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib".`

Does cc_test has env_path option?

I want to do like this

```
cc_test( 
*** 
*** 
test_env = ['/usr/local/lib'] 
)
```

and I can test in this cmd:`./bazel test @xxx//xxx:xxx_test --test_output=errors` I dont want to write `"--test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"` when I want to test

now if I run this cmd:`./bazel test @xxx//xxx:xxx_test --test_output=errors` will get this error:

```
/home/alex.sh/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alex.sh/c973fcd5ba7eef8db46b22b84af3a149/bazel-sandbox/3561058496653596424/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/external/feature_generator/featur\
e_generator/gbdt_test.runfiles/__main__/external/feature_generator/feature_generator/gbdt_test: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such fi\
le or directory
```

Comment: Sorry can you add more details on what is the problem exactly? E.g. what you would like to do and what happen when you try to do it?

Comment: I want to do like this

cc_test(
    ***
    ***
   test_env = ['/usr/local/lib']
)

and I can test in this cmd:./bazel test @xxx//xxx:xxx_test --test_output=errors

I dont want to write "--test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib" when I want to test

Comment: Why do you need to add the test env? Do you have a bazelrc that pass more option to Bazel?

Comment: I update my question~
I thihk maybe libzstd.so is in the /usr/loca/lib, when bazel run test,can't find it.

Comment: Sry, I dont use bazelrc, bazelrc file can solve this question?0.0

Comment: Ok yes you can put the flag in a bazelrc to not have to specify it on the command line, see https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-user-manual.html#bazelrc

But I was more asking because it seems like a bug that you have to specify that option for test but not for build actions.

Comment: Yes,I think maybe linkopt has bug.I write "-L/usr/local/lib" in it,but when I run the test,run option not found "-L/usr/local/lib"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can add the flag to your [~/.bazelrc file](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-user-manual.html#baze%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blrc), e.g.:

```
test --test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

However, the fact that test action cannot find LD_LIBRARY_PATH while build action can sounds like a bug to me, you should file an issue on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new